# Storage Optimisation: JSON vs String with delimiters

Tags: json, string, optimization, storage, delimiter

The below JSON file costs 163 bytes to store.

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "station": 6,
      "category": 1034,
      "type": 5
    },
    {
      "station": 3,
      "category": 1171,
      "type": 7
    },
  ]
}
```

But, If the values are put together as a string with delimiters ',' and '_', `6_1034_5,3_1171_7` costs only 17 bytes.

What are the problems with this approach?

Thank you.

Comment: There are no problems with this approach, known generally as CSV, as long as the format is documented, since it is far less self-documenting than JSON.

Comment: In your case since you’re not storing strings that may contain your separator, it’s safe to do that if you don’t mind a bit of overhead exploding the lines and working with array indexes or whatever is the best way to work with it depending on your application language. I did something similar to save bytes on websocket communication, dropped bw usage by some 25% in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

The problems that I have seen with this sort of approach are mainly centered around maintainability.

With the delimited approach, the properties of your location items are identified by ordinal. Since there are all numbers, there is nothing to tell you whether the first segment is the station, category, or type; you must know that in advance. Someone new to your code base may not know that and therefore introduce bugs.

Right now all of your data are integers, which are relatively easy to encode and decode and do not risk conflicting with your delimiters. However, if you need to add user-supplied text at some point, you run the risk of that text containing your delimiters. In that case, you will have to invent an escaping/encoding mechanism to ensure that you can reliably detect your delimiters. This may seem simple, but it is more difficult than you may suspect. I've seen it done incorrectly many times.

Using a well-known structured text format like XML or JSON has the advantages that it has fully developed and tested rules for dealing with all types of text, and there are fully developed and tested libraries for reading and writing it.

Depending on your circumstances, this concern over the amount of storage could be a micro-optimization. You might want to try some capacity calculations (e.g., how much actual storage is required for X items) and compare that to the expected number of items vs. the expected amount of storage that will be available.